# Downloading subtitles using youtube_dl

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking to download a video with subtitles using the Youtube_dl library. Currently, I am able to download a single video at a time but I am unable to download subtitles with it.

Currently, my implementation is:

```
import youtube_dl

link = input('Please enter a url link:\n')

youtube_dl_options = {}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(youtube_dl_options) as youtube_dl_client:
    youtube_dl_client.download([link])
```

I would like to be able to download the subtitle as well as the video with it.

Comment: Did you check the documentation of youtube_dl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The youtube_dl project is hosted on github (https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py)

Looking at the YoutubeDL module it looks like there are a bunch of options (see lines 142-298, the one you want is on line 183).

You can pass the option using the dictionary `ydl_opts`

Try changing `ydl_opts` to this:

```
ydl_opts = {"writesubtitles": True}
```